# browser not respondig after return false in onblur event

Tags: javascript

I am Using this piece of code at onblur event of a dynamically generated Textbox:

```
var allowed="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ;     
     for(i=0;i<document.getElementById("FNAME").value.length;i++)    
      {       
     if(allowed.indexOf(document.getElementById("FNAME").value.charAt(i)) == -1)           {       
      alert("FIRST NAME should be Alphabet");     
       return false;       
    }         
 }         
 var flag=false;    
         for(j=0;j<document.getElementById("FNAME").value.length;j++)   
       {  
         if(document.getElementById("FNAME").value.charAt(j)!=" ")    
       {         
   flag=true;      
      break;       
    }        
 }     
     if(flag==false)        
  {         
  alert("Please  Enter  FIRST NAME");      
      return false;   
       };
```

Sometimes it runs without any problem, and sometimes Browser get hanged and message of Explorer stopped working is populated(Using IE10 in IE8 mode)

unable to trace out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. It is also doing the same thing which I understood from your code:

**Html:**

```
<input id="FNAME" value="test" type="text" onblur="validateName();"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateName(){
    var fName = document.getElementById("FNAME").value;
    var charCode = 0;
    if(fName.length > 0) {
         for(var i = 0; i < fName.length; i++)    
         {                
              charCode = fName.charCodeAt(i);
              if((charCode < 65 || charCode > 122)) {       
                  alert("FIRST NAME should be Alphabet");     
                  return false;       
              }
         }
    } else {
        alert("Please  Enter  FIRST NAME");
    }
}
```